# Full Outer Join on two subsets of the same table (Postgres 9.5)

Tags: postgresql, join

I want to do a full outer join on two distinct subsets of the same table and I was hoping to do this without writing a CTE or a subquery. I have data that looks like this:

```
with test as
(
select
  'auths' as source,
  'a1' as source_id,
  'peter' as name

union all

select
  'auths' as source,
  'a1' as source_id,
  'lauren' as name

union all

select
  'claims' as source,
  'c1' as source_id,
  'lauren' as name

union all

select
  'claims' as source,
  'c3' as source_id,
  'Jeff' as name
)
```

The result of this looks something like:

```
source  source_id   name
auths   a1          peter
auths   a1          lauren
claims  c1          lauren
claims  c3          Jeff
```

So the idea here is that I have two sources in this table, call it "auths" and "claims". In this particular example, the name 'lauren' appears in both rows where the source is 'auths' and 'claims'. The name peter only appears for 'auths' and the name Jeff only appears for 'claims'.

I want to do a full outer join on two subsets of the table where the subsets are defined by the value of `source` and the join condition is specified by `name`. For example,

```
select 
  coalesce(auths.name, claims.name) as name,
  auths.source as auths_source,
  auths.source_id as auths_source_id,
  claims.source as claims_source,
  claims.source_id as claims_source_id
from (select * from test where source = 'auths') as auths
full outer join (select * from test where source = 'claims') as claims
  on auths.name = claims.name
```

and the desired result looks like

```
name    auths_source    auths_source_id claims_source   claims_source_id
peter   auths             a1        
lauren  auths             a1                claims            c1
Jeff                                        claims            c3
```

Basically the idea is that when there's a match, it gets stored in the same row. When there's not a match it gets stored as two separate rows.

I was wondering if there's a way to do this without using subqueries. For example, I tried

```
select
  coalesce(auths.name, claims.name) as name,
  auths.source as auths_source,
  auths.source_id as auths_source_id,
  claims.source as claims_source,
  claims.source_id as claims_source_id
from test as auths
  full outer join test as claims
    on auths.source = 'auths'
      and claims.source = 'claims'
      and auths.name = claims.name
```

But this doesn't work because since it's a full outer join, the result will still return everything in `test` for both `auths` and `claims`. For example, the result returned from this is:

```
name    auths_source    auths_source_id claims_source   claims_source_id
peter   auths                  a1       
lauren  auths                  a1           claims             c1
lauren  claims                 c1       
Jeff    claims                 c3       
peter                                       auths              a1
Jeff                                        claims             c3
lauren                                      auths              a1
```

This is not what I want because there are extra rows in `auths_source` where the value is `claims` (similar for `claims_source` where the value is `auths` and this is happening because the full outer join returns all rows no matter what.

Thanks!

Comment: I think it can be done with the use of a suitable `where` clause - see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select
  coalesce(auths.name, claims.name) as name,
  auths.source as auths_source,
  auths.source_id as auths_source_id,
  claims.source as claims_source,
  claims.source_id as claims_source_id
from test as auths
full outer join test as claims
  on auths.source = 'auths'
  and claims.source = 'claims'
  and auths.name = claims.name
where coalesce(auths.source, 'auths') = 'auths' 
  and coalesce(claims.source, 'claims') = 'claims'
```

This is basically your statement, with the addition of the `where` clause.